# No puedo actualizar un estado con la pagina actual cuando Navigator ejecuta su método pop

Tags: javascript, react-native

No puedo actualizar el estado de mi App.js con la pagina actual cuando Navigator ejecuta su método pop en React-Native (0.26).

Yo actualizo el estado con la `function` goto.

```
  _goto(currentPage, scene) {
    this.setState({currentPage});
    this._navigator.push({
      id: currentPage,
    });
  }
```

Este es la función que renderiza las escenas del Navigator.

```
  _renderScene(route, nav) {
    curPage = route.id;
    switch (route.id) {
       ...
   }
```

Teng ona funcion que se ejecuta cuando presiono el boton de atras en Android.

```
  _patras(){
    if(curPage != 'MainPage' && curPage != 'SplashPage'){
      this._navigator.pop();
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Y este es el método render de mi App.js donde tengo el TabBar.

```
var currentPage = this.state.currentPage;
if (currentPage != 'SplashPage'){
  if (this.isAndroid){
    TBar = (<TabBar goto={(page) => this._goto(page)} currentPage={currentPage}/>);
  } else {
    TBar = (<TabBarIOS goto={(page) => this._goto(page)} currentPage={currentPage}/>);
  }
}
```

Uso la página actual para cambiar el estilo y desabilitar el boton del TabBar que le correspone. Con este código me funciona bien si avanzo pero al momento de dar hacia atrás no se me actualiza dado que solo lo puedo coger a través del goto. Si pongo un this.setState en el metodo renderScene se bloquea la aplicación.

¿Cuál seria la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debe ocurrir es que tabbar crea un nuevo navigator lo cual hace que dentro de ese nuevo navegador la ruta anterior no exista, por eso no puede volver a una ruta que no existe dentro del navegador.

Mi recomendación es usar react-native-router-flux que permite usar el atributo clone que copia la ruta en el navegador permitiendo regresar desde cualquier view.